# Как прервать Thread, который блокируется на чтении данных из потока ввода-вывода? ?

Tags: java, многопоточность, io

Хочу, завершаиь треды которые читают из сетевого потока данные по Thread.interrupt (), однако тред блокируется на операции чтения и висит замертво. Как можно порешать?

Comment: Используйте неблокирующее чтение. Асинхронные (неблокирующие) процедуры чтения из потоков содержатся в `java.nio.*` (вместо `java.io.*`). Тут https://habrahabr.ru/post/235585/ подробно описаны отличия.

Comment: в плюсовом коде я применял следующий метод - когда нужно закрыть тред, который висит на чтении/записи, то нужно закрыть "подключение". Либо послать сигнал (тут с жавой будет сложнее). Тред, который читал/писал должен понять, что произошла ошибка и сокет закрыт и корректно завершить работу своего треда.

Comment: Если у вас сокеты, надо настроить таймаут.